# Group two nodes by value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

```
    <Item>
        <Description>Dog</Description>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Description>Cat</Description>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Description>Turtle</Description>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Description>Hedgehog</Description>
    </Item>
```

not sorting but I need Hedgehog always under Dog

Would this be possible using xsl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you really want as an output, but this always puts the Item nodes in the Dog, Hedgehog and others order.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Items">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Item[Description='Dog']"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Item[Description='Hedgehog']"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Item[Description!='Hedgehog' and Description!='Dog']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Item">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can try it here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWEamLr